# PHP Curl return 403

Tags: php, curl

I have an url need to get using CURL PHP. When I tried to setup PHP curl as below, I got 403 error

```
$url = "http://r3---sn-ogueln76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?initcwndbps=22007500&signature=111AEFD82398870EA1643F228D98E7D5834FB654.1CA4909304F857122728B00FC24CD06C751FC181&dur=3812.809&nh=IgpwcjAzLm5ydDE5KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&sver=3&sparams=dur,id,initcwndbps,ip,ipbits,itag,lmt,mime,mm,mn,ms,mv,nh,pl,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&lmt=1460861599174672&mime=video/mp4&ip=45.32.11.179&mm=31&source=youtube&pl=25&mn=sn-ogueln76&mt=1461253133&mv=m&id=o-AHFL53t2W9hKDUR3w8WBd5DOA-1Joopi7CtioNWE1jG4&ms=au&expire=1461274970&key=yt6&upn=zmxYuJKDITA&ratebypass=yes&ipbits=0&itag=18&fexp=9405185,9408350,9416126,9416891,9420452,9422542,9422596,9425077,9426927,9427773,9428398,9430014,9430031,9431012,9431522,9433094,9433097,9433653,9434126,9434765&signature=";
$xx = curl_init();
$head[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$head[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$head[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$head[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
$verbose = fopen('tmp.log', 'w+');
curl_setopt($xx, CURLOPT_STDERR, $verbose);
var_dump(curl_exec($xx));
```

Here is the error:

```
string(223) "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden Last-Modified: Wed, 02 May 2007 10:26:10 GMT Content-Type: text/plain Content-Length: 0 Connection: close X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 16:15:25 GMT Server: gvs 1.0 "
```

But when I try to request same url which CURL shell (command prompt). I got 302 code
[image: 302 code]

I am suppesting that php curl encoded my request so that the server don't allow and return 403.

If you have any idea, please help. Thank you very much.